# Leaving an index out each time

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to write a program which computes the variable called `P` for a set of numbers (`i=1:10`), except for one number (`ind`), which is chosen each time.

The first time `P` is calculated for `i=1:10` and for example the number 4 is chosen as `ind` and used and we don't want it to be included in the next iteration. So this next iteration `P` has to be calculated for `i=[1:3 5:10]`.

How can i handle this? What I have this far is:

```
for i=1:10

    i=1:i
        t = sum(Job(i,2))
    i=1:10
        P = mean(Job(i,2))
        Index= Job(i,4)/Job(i,2)*exp(-max(Job(i,1)-Job(i,2)-t,0)/2*P)
        X=max(Index)
        ind=find(Index >= X)
    completion_time(Job(ind,3))= machine_free_time + Job(ind,2)
    machine_free_time = completion_time(Job(ind,3))
    Lateness(Job(ind,3))= completion_time(Job(ind,3)) - Job(ind,1)
    Tardiness(Job(ind,3))= max(Lateness(Job(ind,3)),0)
end
```

Comment: I dont understand your loops. Can you edit them so they're proper Matlab syntax?

Comment: the part that i don't know how to write is i=1:10 in 
 
i=1:10 
P = mean(Job(i,2))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways of doing this:

1. Remove elements from a vector

   ```
   idcs = 1:10; % initially all values are included from 1 to 10
   for ii=1:10
       idx = choose one out of idcs
       % do your calculation
       % remove idx from idcs
       idcs(idcs==idx)=[];
   end
   ```
2. Use a 2nd vector to keep hold of which values are already used:

   ```
   idcs = 1:10;
   valused=false(size(idcs));
   for ii=1:10
       idx = choose one out of idcs(~valused)
       % do your calculation
       % set the used value to true
       valused(idcs=idx)=true;
   end
   ```

So for example to use this 2nd method with the thing you're trying to do, I think it'll go like this:

```
vector_i = 1:10
vector_i_used = false(size(vector_i));

for kk=1:10 % main loop
    P = calculateP( vector_i(~vector_i_used) );
    % ...
    ind = calculateInd(P, vector_i(~vector_i_used));
    vector_i_used(vector_i==ind) = true;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a different approach. Check to see if the value is already included, and then don't include it if you have already tested it.  I'll leave the code, and figuring out `newDone`, to you, but this approach should work.

```
alreadyDone=false(10,1);
for i=1:10
   if (alreadyDone(i))
      %Do stuff here
   end
   alreadyDone(newDone)=true;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use an if/then statement to skip the desired index in the loop:

```
   skipThisIndex = [];
   for ii=1:10
      if ii~=skipThisIndex
         %  Do calculations
      end
      %Determine which index you want to skip next
      skipThisIndex = indexToSkipNext;
   end
```